# nsnumberformatter numberfromstring returns nil

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a string containing a pure number, but numberFromString returns nil.
Any idea why?

My code:

```
NSString *fText = @"33";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter;
NSNumber *fNum = [formatter numberFromString:fText];
NSLog(@"Number is %i", [fNum integerValue];
```

prints 0, and debugs as NIL.

Am I missing something in the formatter properties?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Your NSNumberFormatter is not initialized, so it is nil, and returning nil for the NSNumber.
Try:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
NSNumber* fNum = [formatter numberFromString:fText];
```

It should work then.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can't believed I missed that... :-)